# "No Matching Files Found" Running Sigcheck (Node.js) with execSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a program in Javascript (Node). In this program I want to get an executable's version number with the Windows Sigcheck tool, but it is giving me "No matching files found."

I can run Sigcheck from the command prompt and it works fine:
[Sigcheck finds the executable, and the output is the executable's version number.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyOXk.png)

But when I run the same command through Node's child_process execSync(), Sigcheck cannot find the file. I run this code:

```
let appVersionNumber = execSync('\\path\\to\\sigcheck.exe -n "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2017\bin\maya.exe"');
```

And I get this output instead:
["No matching files found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8CsQ.png)

How can I run Sigcheck in Node to get the executable's version number? It is definitely running Sigcheck because it is displaying the banner, but I do not understand why it can't find the executable. Any help would be appreciated- thanks!

Comment: Please put the output in your question, not an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes in the param string too:

```
let appVersionNumber = execSync('\\path\\to\\sigcheck.exe -n "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2017\\bin\\maya.exe"');
```

Otherwise they'll just be skipped (it's how slashes are treated in string literal in JavaScript), and you'll get the wrong path with no files for sigcheck to, well, check.

BTW, if I were you, I'd probably have put those pathes into separate variables:

```
const sigcheckPath = '\\path\\to\\sigcheck.exe';
const appPath      = 'C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2017\\bin\\maya.exe';
let appVersionNumber = execSync(`${sigcheckPath} "${appPath}"`);
```